# Efficient way to solve modulo equation with huge numbers

Tags: performance, equation, modulo

I am trying to solve the following equation `(x * 0x5DEECE66D + 11) mod 2^47 = 0x310CDAF20000` which [WolframAlpha is able to solve in a few seconds](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x*%2025214903917%20%2B%2011%29%20mod%202%5E47%20%3D%2053931282661376)

I came up with the trivial following `C++` code, replacing modulo with `&`, which sadly isn't efficient enough and take ages to finish:

```
auto target = 0x310CDAF20000LL;
auto devider = 0x5DEECE66DLL;
auto mask = 1LL << 48 - 1;
auto i = 1LL;

while (1) {
    if ((i * devider + 11) & mask == target) {
        printf("%llx", i);
        break;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let start here

```
25214903917 * x = 53931282661365 (mod 2^47)
```

from Euler's theorem you know, that

```
25214903917 ^ phi(2^47) = 1 (mod 2^47)
```

where Euler's totient is easily calculated as (2^47)/2 = 2^46 in this case. So

```
25214903917 * 25214903917 ^ (phi(2^47) -1) = 1 (mod 2^47)
25214903917 * 25214903917 ^ (2^46 -1) = 1 (mod 2^47)
25214903917 * (53931282661365 * 25214903917 ^ (2^46 -1)) = 53931282661365 (mod 2^47)
x = 53931282661365 * 25214903917 ^ (2^46 -1) (mod 2^47)
```

you can use exponentiation by squaring for calculation the exponentiation. The code is really simple (in C#)

```
long desiredResult = 53931282661365;
long q = 25214903917;

long invq = 1;
long tmp = q;
for(int i = 0; i < 46; ++i)
{
    // tmp is q^(2^i)
    invq = (invq * tmp) & 0x7FFFFFFFFFFF;
    tmp = (tmp * tmp) & 0x7FFFFFFFFFFF; 
}
// invq is 105417217348453

long x = (invq * desiredResult) & 0x7FFFFFFFFFFF;
// x is 91896827357865

long test = (q * x) & 0x7FFFFFFFFFFF;
// test is 53931282661365
```

the whole solution is `n * 2^47 + x`, corresponding to the WolframAlpha

Comment: That's insane. I love math. Gonna read your comment few more times to understand exactly what you did.

Answer (score 0):

If `(x * 0x5DEECE66D + 11) mod 2^47 = 0x310CDAF20000` is true, then `(x * 0x5DEECE66D) mod 2^47 = 310CDAF1FFF5` will be true (for non-negative `x` maybe, depending on how `mod` is defined).

Shifting everything to the left by 17 bits won't change anything. In other words, if `(x * 0x5DEECE66D) mod 2^47 = 310CDAF1FFF5` then `(x * 2EF767336800000) mod 2^64 = 866D78FFFA800000`.

For computers, with 64 bit (unsigned) integers and standard "truncation to fit" this means that the `mod` can be deleted.

Next; if `(x * 2EF767336800000) mod 2^64 = y` then `( (x+1) * 2EF767336800000) mod 2^64 = (y + 2EF767336800000) mod 2^64`.

In other words, starting from `x = 0` (where it's obvious that `(x * 2EF767336800000) mod 2^64 = 0`) you can use "add then AND" to determine the result for `x = 1`, then do the same for `x = 2`, then ...

This leads to:

```
    auto target = 0x310CDAF20000LL;
    auto devider = 0x5DEECE66DLL;
    auto i = 1LL;

    auto t = (target - 11) << 17;
    auto d = devider << 17;
    uint64_t temp = 0;

    do {
        temp += d;
        i++;
    } while(temp != t);
```

The step beyond that is realizing that if `(x * 2EF767336800000) mod 2^64 = y` then `( (x+8) * 2EF767336800000) mod 2^64 = (y + 2EF767336800000 * 8) mod 2^64`. This means that if you have 8 starting values (`x = 0` to `x = 7`) you could do 8 values for `x` in parallel using SIMD.

Comment: That's a good approach, sadly it is not as near as fast as I need it to be. I need to solve this for `0xFFFF` cases for `0x310CDAF20000 + i, for i from 0 to 0xFFFF`. I thought I will understand how to solve it for that one case and then apply the solution for the rest of the cases.

Comment: @DanielCohen: In that case you'd determine `temp`, then at the end of the loop check if `temp` is any of the (up to 65536) values you're still looking for. That way it shouldn't be 65536 times as expensive (and might only be 4 times as expensive).

Comment: I ended up using wolframscript to just get what I needed. It is obviously not a proper solution, but it seems this is a difficult mathematical question, so it seems reasonable to use a mathematical compute engine.